# how to pause execution of javascript function and resume once it get user input

Tags: javascript

In the below code, Calculate is a function that calculates the sum of two numbers. I am
calling calculate on the load of page i.e., onload event. getValueOfA and getValueOfB will return some
value only if the user enters some value in respective textfields.

Problem:

1. Calculate function should wait until it gets value from getValueOfA() function and then execute the further code.
2. It should not pause other functionalities on-page.

```
function calculate(){
  let a = getValueOfA(); 
  let b = getValueOfB();
  console.log(a+b);
}
```

Comment: You're looking to use either Promises or callbacks. This is homework so -1 from me and I hope from others.

Comment: Instead of running `calculate` when the page loads, you can run it when the user inputs text into a text field. Then in `calculate` you can check if both textfields have values before doing your calculation and returning

Comment: And why do you call it when page loads if no numbers will be entered yet??

Comment: You should either call the function after `a` and `b` have been initialized (so it would look like this: `function calc(a,b){console.log(a+b);}`) or make `getValueOfA` and `getValueOfB` return a promise or accept a callBack function that will signal the `calculate` to print `a + b`

Answer (score -1):

```
async function calculate(){
  let a = await getValueOfA(); 
  let b = await getValueOfB();
  console.log(a+b);
}
```

Check for more about async and await on MDN.
URL: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function